# "make: yacc: Command not found" after installing Bison

Tags: bison, yacc

While running a makefile in gcc 4.1.2 (linux 5), I got the following error

```
make: yacc: Command not found
```

By googling, I came to know that this error can be rectified by installing Bison-GNU parser generator.
But even after installing Bison, I get the same error.

How can this error be solved?

Comment: What OS are you under?  Sounds like some linux distro, but I'm not sure which.  Also, that error is pretty self-explanatory: what happens when you run `whereis yacc`?

Comment: the output of whereis yacc is yacc: /usr/share/man/man1p/yacc.1p.gz

Comment: That's a compressed man page, not an executable.

Comment: That means that your $PATH does not include the yacc executable-- that's just its manual page.  I'd suggest trying to find where `yacc` is, and finding why it's not on your $PATH.  This is more of a ServerFault or SuperUser question BTW.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the looks of things, your makefile is expecting a `yacc` executable to be available and either it's not, or it's not on your path.

Since `bison` is supposed to be compatible with `yacc` so the first thing I would try would be:

```
alias yacc="bison"
```

and try again. On my setup, `/usr/bin/yacc` is simply a script containing:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec '/usr/bin/bison' -y "$@"
```

You can try to locate the `yacc` or `bison` executables with the command (substituting bison for yacc if need be):

```
which yacc
```

But they're probably in one of the standard places like `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I would suggest seeing if `bison` exists first, but yes, good to know.

Comment: yes Bison exists. The output of "which bison" command is "/usr/bin/bison". But even after giving "alias yacc="bison", I get the same error.

Comment: Then the alias is probably disappearing, or it's using a shell that doesn't have aliases. If `which yacc` does not turn up a valid executable, create your own `/usr/bin/yacc` executable along the lines of the one given in the answer. If _that_ doesn't work then your makefile is almost certainly not seeing `/usr/bin` when it's running.

Comment: Well, the alias works fine. "which yaac" gives "alias yacc='bison'    /usr/bin/bison". The error has been resolved. Thanks paxdibolo.

Answer (score 52):

Run the following command on your terminal to install bison,
**yacc** executables and configurations.**yacc** comes along with bison

Also you need **byacc** for a full functional **yacc**

```
sudo apt-get install bison -y
sudo apt-get install byacc -y
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 as installed - had bison but not byacc. Thanks for tip. (Upvoted).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue on RHEL7.

Find where bison is:

```
$:which bison

*/bin/bison*
```

Create symlink to bison from yacc:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/bison /bin/yacc
```

And that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created the alias file on my Ubuntu 16 system, while testing then I found that bison was missing so I installed bison which gave me an error about the link that I had made for /usr/bin/yacc, so the bison install creates the lnk file itself for yacc on Ubuntu 16.