# make file : yacc command not found and [y.tab.c] error 127 after installing bison

Tags: makefile, centos, bison, yacc

There is a given r-tree code by Toni Guttman(it's been modified for my homework), however, if I change an parameter(the dimension of the node), then "make" will cause such errors:

```
yacc y.spec
make: yacc：command not found
make: *** [y.tab.c] error 127
```

I've installed bison and flex, and "which yacc" shows that

```
alias yacc='bison'
/usr/bin/bison
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Here is the "Makefile":

```
# %W% %G%
# use flag -O for optimized code, slower compile
FLAGS=

SRC= main.c index.c newtid.c node.c rectangle.c \
    printstats.c clock.c y.spec allocate.c error.c\
    split.l.c \
    split.q.c \
    split.e.c

HEADERS= options.h macros.h index.h assert.h

ALL= $(SRC) $(HEADERS) split.l.h split.q.h split.e.h

OBJ= main.o index.o newtid.o node.o rectangle.o \
    printstats.o clock.o y.tab.o allocate.o error.o

OBJLIN= split.l.o
OBJQ= split.q.o
OBJEXP= split.e.o

$(OBJ): $(HEADERS)
$(OBJLIN): $(HEADERS) split.l.h
$(OBJQ): $(HEADERS) split.q.h
$(OBJEXP): $(HEADERS) split.e.h

# assembler chokes if graphics.c is compiled with -g option, do it without.
# graphics.o: graphics.c $(HEADERS)
#   cc -c graphics.c

# assembler chokes if y.tab.c is compiled with -g option, do it without.
# y.tab.o: y.tab.c $(HEADERS)
#   cc -c y.tab.c

.c.o: $(HEADERS)
    cc -c $(FLAGS) $*.c

linear: $(OBJ) $(OBJLIN)
    cc $(FLAGS) $(OBJ) $(OBJLIN) -lm -o linear

quad: $(OBJ) $(OBJQ)
    cc $(FLAGS) $(OBJ) $(OBJQ) -lm -o quad

exp: $(OBJ) $(OBJEXP)
    cc $(FLAGS) $(OBJ) $(OBJEXP) -lm -o exp

y.tab.c: y.spec $(HEADERS)
    yacc y.spec

edit:
    sccs edit $(SRC) $(HEADERS) split.l.h split.q.h split.o.h

unedit:
    sccs unedit $(ALL)
    rm -f tags

delta:
    sccs delta $(ALL)
    rm -f tags

get:
    sccs get $(ALL)

clean:
    rm -f *.o core y.tab.c tags

tags: $(SRC)
    ctags *.c

lint:
    rm -f lint.out
    lint *.c > lint.out
```

Comment: please refer this solution:
[add alias to solve it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733238/make-yacc-command-not-found-after-installing-bison

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `yacc` installed, as you've seen.  Changing an alias in your shell won't help, because it's make that is trying to run the `yacc` command, not the shell.  You have to edit your makefile, and add a line like:

```
YACC = bison -y
```

(the `-y` flag makes bison behave like yacc)

Since you didn't show your actual makefile we can't be sure that this will do it, but it's likely.

EDIT:

I your makefile above, change the reference to `yacc` to say `bison -y` instead.

Your makefile is not following many best practices but that's for another day.

Comment: I know nothing about "Makefile" ... T T

Answer (score 1):

manually add this script /usr/bin/yacc is simply a script containing:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec '/usr/bin/bison' -y "$@"
```